# OCR on Live Webcam Feed: Image height is zero, Invalid IHDR data

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

So I'm pretty new to openCV and google vision but I am attempting to use edge detection to identify numbers in a specific area of a tag. The code runs and works fine when the tag is in view of the camera, however when the tag isn't in view I get a libpng warning: Image height is zero in IDHR and libpng error: Invalid IHDR data

I have tried checking if the frame is not Nonetype and that ret is True but I can't figure out how to have it just not output anything until a tag is in the frame.

Below are images of a sample frame and the output from my edge dectection
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVHFm.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb3Z5.jpg

```
import io
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import re

from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform 
import imutils

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types

# Instantiates a client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
def detect_text(path):
    global lotid
    """Detects text in the file."""
    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = types.Image(content=content)
    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    texts = response.text_annotations
    string = ''

    for text in texts:
        string+=' ' + text.description
        string = string[0:9]
    return string

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):  
# cap.isOpened()

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200, 255)

    # find contours in the edge map, then sort them by their size in descending order
    cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
    displayCnt = None

    for c in cnts:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c,True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c,.02 * peri, True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            displayCnt = approx
            break

    # extract the display, apply a perspective transform to it
    warped = four_point_transform(gray, displayCnt.reshape(4, 2))
    output = four_point_transform(frame, displayCnt.reshape(4, 2))

    (h,w) = warped.shape
    (dX,dY) = (int(w*.8),int(h*.45))
    crop = warped[20:dY,w-dX:w-20]


    file = 'live.png'
    cv2.imwrite(file,crop)

    # print OCR text
    print(detect_text(file))

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',crop)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) &0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

    # print('Confidence: {}'.format(detect_text.confidence))

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Could you add your original input image?

Comment: @nathancy Yep just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may do it with try, catch? It's quite simple and works fine with Python, check this out [Try Except in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

Comment: This keeps my code running however I still receive the error message for every instance. Additionally, because of that I can't terminate my code unless i physically close the terminal out

Comment: can you tell me on which part of the code it bugs out so I can back trace the problem

Comment: It bugs when it hits the warped variable because displayCnt is type None

Comment: well now it's code flow issue, I would suggest you making a bool flag that will tell you if displayCnt is None, and if it is just skip the unwanted lines if that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @PetarMarkovic I re-positioned my try exception statement around my warped, output variables and print statements and it works just as expected.